# C# wpf determine whether any of controls inside grid has a focus

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, focus

I have WPF window with a grid and some controls inside.
Is it possible to determine whether any of controls inside grid has a focus?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
   var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(mygrid);
```

Comment: what about keyboard focus, i think this will be apt only for logical focus

Comment: Also should we need to set the FocusManager.IsFocusScope =true for the grid?